# How to connect to database Openshift with Silex

Tags: php, database, git, openshift, silex

I want to connect my silex Application to my Database with Openshift,

So i have these lines in my file bootstrap.php

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

App::$app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
    'db.options' => array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host' => constant("DB_HOST"),
        'dbname' => constant("DB_NAME"),
        'user' => constant("DB_USER"),
        'password' => constant("DB_PASS"),
        'port' => constant("DB_PORT"),
    ),
));
```

I call several working services

And the website work in Local (with local connection)

When i push with git i have this error in my logs (when i update the website) :

```
[Mon Dec 22 08:10:17 2014] [error] [client 127.12.51.129] PHP Fatal error:  Clas
s 'Doctrine\\DBAL\\Configuration' not found in /var/lib/openshift/548b027efcf933
a1dd0000fe/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Provider/DoctrineS
erviceProvider.php on line 90
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies on OpenShift?

Comment: Do you have doctrine/dbal in your composer.json?

Comment: Yes i have doctrine/dbal in my vendor. 

My depencies on Openshift ? 
I installed PHP5.4, MySQL 5.1 and phpMyAdmin 4.0.

Comment: Do you have a vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Configuration.php file on your server?

Comment: Yes, the project work in local (so all depencies are presents in the project)